# Use another options value as default in argparse

Tags: python

Is it possible to use another options value as a default in argparse

```
parser.add_argument("--num-1", default='1', help="[OPTIONAL] arg 1")
parser.add_argument("--num-2", default='1', help="[OPTIONAL] arg 2")
```

here if no default value is passed to --num-2 I want to use the same value as num_1 either its default or the input value.

```
parser.parse_args("--num-1 10".split())
```

Namespace(num_1='10', num_2='1') # i.e num_2 should be same as num_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the optional value for `--num-2`. This means if no value is given, the default value will be `None`. You can then test if this is the case after receing the command line arguments. If `--num2` is `None`, set it to equal the value of `--num-1`:

```
parser.add_argument("--num-1", default='1', help="[OPTIONAL] arg 1")
parser.add_argument("--num-2", help="[OPTIONAL] arg 2")
...
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.num_2 is None:
    args.num_2 = args.num_1
```

Or more tersely:

```
args.num_2 = args.num_1 if args.num_2 is None else args.num_2
```

Even more tersely:

```
args.num_2 = args.num_2 or args.num_1
```

Note however that the last method given ***will only*** work if `--num-2` is never a "falsy"

Comment: Your last terse example won't work if the user specifies 0 for num 2 on the command line...

Comment: @Ben True, I assumed the OP wouldn't have such as case. But that's a fair point. I'll add a caveat.